# grid group header child columns evaluated not correctly

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.2

I am new to Extjs 4.2, When I work extjs 3.4 i used groupheader plugin. Now i have problem with column header in grid. I wrote 4 level columns and I have problem with last level child columns. Their height evaluated not correctly.

Problem view

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3gA4A/)

```
+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                  Column 1                      |                      Column 2                         |
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------
|      col11            |    col12               |          col21               |       col22            |
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------+
|  col111   |  col112   |   col121   |  col122   |     col211    |     col212   |             |          |
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------|   col221    |  col222  |
|           problem      space                   | c2111 | c2112 | c2121 | c2122|             |          |
+------------------------------------------------+-------+-------+_------+------+-------------+----------+
|                                                                                                        |
|                                                                                                        |
|                                   store     data                                                       |
|                                                                                                        |
|                                                                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If remove Column2, columns will be correct, Column1 contain 3 level, Column2 contain 4 level, that is why Column1 is rendered not correct, Please give me help if you can, how to fix this, I much time searched on Google this problem, but dont found answer.

This is code of grid

```
Ext.define("ValyutaApp.view.revenue.Republic", {
    extend: "Ext.grid.Panel",
    requires: [
        "Ext.toolbar.Paging",
        "Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature",
        "Ext.form.field.Date",
        "Ext.grid.feature.Summary"
    ],
    alias: "widget.revenue-republic",
    store: "ValyutaApp.store.revenue.Republic",
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.features = me.buildFeatures();
        me.columns = me.buildColumns();
        me.dockedItems = me.buildDockedItems();
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
    buildFeatures: function () {
        return {ftype: "summary"};
    },
    buildColumns: function () {
        return [
            {
                text: "Шундан",
                menuDisabled: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        text: "Микрофирма ва кичик корхоналар",
                        menuDisabled: true,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                text: "Сони",
                                dataIndex: "MFMPSONI",
                                width: 80,
                                //xtype: "numbercolumn",
                                align: "right",
                                summaryType: "sum"
                            },
                            {
                                text: "Суммаси",
                                dataIndex: "MFMPSUM",
                                width: 120,
                                xtype: "numbercolumn",
                                align: "right",
                                summaryType: "sum"
                            }
                        ]

                    },
                    {
                        text: "Микрофирма ва кичик корхоналар тоифасига кирмайдиган",
                        menuDisabled: true,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                text: "Сони",
                                dataIndex: "KFSONI",
                                width: 80,
                                //xtype: "numbercolumn",
                                align: "right",
                                summaryType: "sum"
                            },
                            {
                                text: "Суммаси",
                                dataIndex: "KFSUM",
                                width: 120,
                                xtype: "numbercolumn",
                                align: "right",
                                summaryType: "sum"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                text: "Шу жумладан: Имтиёзлар турлари сони ва суммаси",
                menuDisabled: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        text: "ВМнинг 245-сонли карорига асосан",
                        menuDisabled: true,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                text: "3-а бандига мувофик",
                                menuDisabled: true,
                                columns: [
                                    {
                                        text: "Сони",
                                        dataIndex: "LG3ASONI",
                                        width: 80,
                                        //xtype: "numbercolumn",
                                        align: "right",
                                        summaryType: "sum"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text: "Суммаси",
                                        dataIndex: "LG3ASUM",
                                        width: 120,
                                        xtype: "numbercolumn",
                                        align: "right",
                                        summaryType: "sum"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                text: "3-б бандига мувофик",
                                menuDisabled: true,
                                columns: [
                                    {
                                        text: "Сони",
                                        dataIndex: "LG3BSONI",
                                        width: 80,
                                        //xtype: "numbercolumn",
                                        align: "right",
                                        summaryType: "sum"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text: "Суммаси",
                                        dataIndex: "LG3BSUM",
                                        width: 120,
                                        xtype: "numbercolumn",
                                        align: "right",
                                        summaryType: "sum"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Берилган имтиёзлар",
                        menuDisabled: true,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                text: "Сони",
                                dataIndex: "LGHUKSONI",
                                width: 80,
                                //xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                                align: 'right',
                                summaryType: 'sum'
                            },
                            {
                                text: "Суммаси",
                                dataIndex: "LGHUSUM",
                                width: 120,
                                xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                                align: 'right',
                                summaryType: 'sum'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    buildDockedItems: function () {
        return [
            {
                xtype: "toolbar",
                dock: "top",
                items: [
                    {
                        text: "Excel",
                        iconCls: "excel-icon",
                        action: "excel"
                    },
                    "&nbsp;Период:&nbsp;",
                    {
                        xtype: "datefield",
                        name: "period",
                        width: 120
                    },
                    {
                        iconCls: "ok-icon",
                        action: "ok"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: "pagingtoolbar",
                dock: "bottom",
                store: this.store,
                displayInfo: true
            }
        ];
    }

});
```

This is code of window

```
Ext.define("ValyutaApp.view.revenue.Area",{
    extend: "Ext.window.Window",
    alias: "widget.revenue-area",
    title: "Тушум тугрисида МАЪЛУМОТ",
    width: 700,
    height: 400,
    autoScroll: true,
    closable: true,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    maximizable: true,
    layout:'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'revenue-republic'
    }]
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle example or at least a screenshot of the result

Comment: Please I have added jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround for you. Add `style` to the first four columns:

```
style: "padding-top: 6px; padding-bottom: 5px;"
```

It is not very elegant, but you can use it till you find out where the problem comes from. Here is the result: [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gA4A/1/)

Comment: Darin, Thank you very much for your answer! Your answer is very useful  and i hope to find core of problem